# The .vbs scripts are only partially included in my .msi installer, part of them is omitted. Is that important?

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I have to modify and installer (install.msi) so that it will read a value from the Windows' registry.
The previous version uses Visual Basic scripts to read other values, so I modified it.
For some reason, I don't see any change in the behaviour of the new installer, but also i don't see any error during the execution of the installer.
I finally decided to open the install.msi using Notepad++ and I found my script there, written in clear ASCII, including comments. BUT the script contained in the install.msi is not completed, a string is not closed and many lines are omitted.

I will give an example, let's suppose this is the ORIGINAL SCRIPT written by me, starting from half of it:

```
    If (trallalla= "" ) Then
        Session.Property ("trallallero") = "NOT_INSTALLED"

    Else

' ... OTHER 70 LINES OF CODE, THEN THE FILE ENDS WITH THE FOLLOWING F

    Function appendSlash(Byval path)

    If( not right(path,1)="\" ) Then
        path = path & "\"
    End If
    
    appendSlash = path

End Function
```

An the following is the same script as I found in the install.msi, starting from the same line; please note the line 3 and compare it with the original code:

```
    If (trallalla= "" ) Then
        Session.Property ("trall    End If    ' this line is not legal!!  a string is not closed and many lines are missing!
     
' ... the last 18 lines of code are complete and correctly present in the install.msi

    End If

End Function

    Function appendSlash(Byval path)

    If( not right(path,1)="\" ) Then
        path = path & "\"
    End If
    
    appendSlash = path

End Function
```

Could be a problem during the creation of the install.msi that damages my scripts, or the scripts are stored in the msi in a binary way that is not all visible, so the problem is elsewhere in the algorithm?
**The execution of the installer does NOT launch any error.**
I mean, i don't see any reason why my scripts should appear only partially, but this may be normal and the script is still in the install.msi, for some technical reason. Any info?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a Notepad++ display issue, since an MSI file is not a text file? Does it make any difference if you switch to a Hex View? Maybe a dedicated [MSI Viewer](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/msi-viewer/9MZTR9QS01GN?hl=en-us&gl=us) will hep confirm what's in the MSI.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the missing part of the script was in the file, but elsewhere. Anyway the problem was in other settings, when those were repaired, the script started working even if in the installer it was listed in that strange way.